# Fuzzy clustering on non time-series data and the Mfuzz package

Tags: clustering, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I am trying to apply the fuzzy clustering on a dataset that does not have the time series format.

I read some documents about the fuzzy c-means and the package Mfuzz in R. As to my understanding, the Mfuzz package is exclusivity to time series data. But also, in the documents, the mfuzz() is a wrapper function for cmeans() of the e1071 package. And for the cmeans(), it seems to me that there is no data format required (i.e the data does not have to have the time series format).

I read also some documents (http://mfuzz.sysbiolab.eu/) about the theory for Mfuzz, and I do not understand why the data must have the time series format.

My question is that, can we use cmeans() on the non time series data? And why the mfuzz() is used only for the time series data? Can someone help, please?